# JSONDecodeError when parsing funky JSON

Tags: python, json, parsing

Recently, I started working with JSON (with Python 3.7 under Debian 9). This is the first (probably of many) data sets in JSON which I've had the pleasure of working with.

I have used the Python built-in JSON module to interpret arbitrary strings and files. I now have a database with ~5570 rows pertaining information regarding to a given list of servers. There are a lot of things in the pipeline, which I have devised a plan for, but I'm stuck on this particular sanitation.

Here's the code I'm using to parse:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.7
import json


def servers_from_json(file_name):
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())
        servers = [{'asn': item['data']['resource'], 'resource': item['data']['allocations'][0]['asn_name']} for item in data]
        return servers

servers = servers_from_json('working-things/working-format-for-parse')
print(servers)
```

**My motive**

I'm trying to get match each one of these servers to their ASN_NAME (which is a field ripped straight from RIPE's API; thus providing me with information pertaining to the physical dc each server is located at. Then, once that's done I'll write them to an existing SQL table, next to a Boolean.

So, here's where it gets funky. If I run the whole dataset through this I get this **error message**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse-test.py", line 12, in <module>
    servers = servers_from_json('2servers.json')
  File "./parse-test.py", line 7, in servers_from_json
    data = json.loads(f.read())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 38 column 2 (char 1098)
```

I noticed that the problem with my initial data set was that each JSON object wasn't delimited by ,\n. 
Did some cleaning, still no luck.

I then added the first 3(?) objects to a completely clean file and.. success. I can get the script to read and interpret them the way I want.

Here's the data set with the comma delimiter:

```
http://db.farnworth.site/servers.json
```

Here's the working data set:

```
http://db.farnworth.site/working-format.json
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [mre]

Comment: Just FYI, you can load files usin `json.load(f)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is great that you linked the data-set, but as @tripleee correctly states, a MRE would be great. If you do not already know it https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask is also worth a look :-)

Comment: `http://db.farnworth.site/servers.json` is neither comma-separated, nor an array

Comment: you send many JSON data separated by nothing - so you get error. You should create one list with all JSON data - `[{JSON_DATA}, {JSON_DATA}, ...]`

Comment: Sincere apologies guys... The first link should now display the actual file which I have.

Comment: Also, the second link is the minimal reproducible example, with only 3 of the objects in there.

Comment: Hopefully this is enough data to go by... I've broken this problem down repeatedly, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I am here assuming that `|` will not be present as part of the data. And separate each of the information chunks using `|` and then convert it into a list and load each list item using `json` module. Hope it helps!

You can try:

```py
import json
import re

with open("servers.json", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    pattern = re.compile(r'\}\{')
    data = pattern.sub('}|{', data).split('|')
    for item in data:
        server_info = json.loads(item)
        allocations = server_info['data']['allocations']
        for alloc in allocations:
            print(alloc['asn_name'])
```

---

I could read the `output.json` like this

```py
import json
import re

with open("output.json", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    server_info = json.loads(data)  
    for item in server_info:
        allocations = item['data']['allocations']
        for alloc in allocations:
            print(alloc['asn_name'])
```

Comment: Hey, I tried this with both the minimal data set and the full set... To no avail :/

Both are giving me the following output: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse-test.py", line 12, in <module>
    allocations = server_info['data']['allocations']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: I saved the json file from the url you have provided and used that and I am getting all the asn_names without any error. Are you doing something different?

Comment: Not from what I can tell. I'm using Python 3.7, have tried to use 2.7 too. No luck. 

I've tried using the working format too, the one which my original program reads perfectly fine. Still getting the TypeError :/

Comment: anyway the error you are getting is not `JSONDecodeError`. Try to print the first item. i.e. put a `print(server_info)` and `break` after that.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I added a break point after the print(server_info). It printed some ugly JSON which, only when I put it through a JSON formatter, gave me some valid JSON. https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ is the one I used. I also ran the working data set from the second list. Feel a little lost here. Any advice?

Comment: Also, when I pass it the full servers.json file, it freaks out and throws me up a different error :( 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse-test.py", line 11, in <module>
    server_info = json.loads(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

Comment: the ugly json is because it is not pretty printed. you can try `print(json.dumps(server_info, indent=4))`

Comment: Excellent! That definitely works. Thanks for your patience here.

The only thing that I'm left with (after the pretty print) is this error here:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse-test.py", line 13, in <module>
    allocations = server_info['data']['allocations']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Don't know where to start

Comment: check the content of 'data' in the value that is printed.

Comment: post the value of `print(json.dumps(server_info, indent=4))` somewhere so that i can have a look

Comment: http://db.farnworth.site/output.json - This is on the large file... I'll do a run for the smaller example here :)

Comment: YES. Abhilb you my friend are a legend. The output is looking tasty.

Now, the dataset is reporting that there's instances in there in which the "asn_name" reports back multiple fields. I think It's going to be a case of listing the position as I list the asn_name fields as it goes along. Thank you so much for your time and patience here!